# Is it possible to create new category of pinned items for a taskbar shortcut like explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, taskbar, pinning

When you right click Explorer on the taskbar a list of pinned with 2 categories is shown: *Pinned* and *Most recently used*. (I actually disabled the last one)

I was wondering if this is strictly build into the executable or there is a way to change these and create your own category.

I wanted to create an specific category called "Media" (or something like that) so it lists the currently mounted media on the computer.

My best guess is to constantly update the registry with a script running on the background.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine that there is a way to do it, but I'm not exactly sure how.

I do know that Windows store all the information about the JumpLists in the folders

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations
```

Perhaps there is some way to access and edit this data, though I'm not sure.  Microsoft describes how you'd setup the Jump Lists for a new program [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770767.aspx).

Source: http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/15117-I-can-t-pin-a-folder-to-the-taskbar.../page3

Comment: The MSDN link is for programmers who want to support jump-lists, I doubt that it’s possible to set up a jumplist for just any old program (i.e., without being able to make changes to the source-code), at least not without using a third-party program as an intermediary between the program and the user (I recall something like being used in the past to allow you to enable/customize pinning certain programs to the taskbar).